# Add attribute with increasing values

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<article id="2332">content...</article>
<article id="0565">content...</article>
<article id="5686">content...</article>
```

I want to add an attribute "scroll-index" with increasing numbers. As a result, it should be

```
    <article id="2332" data-scroll-index="0">content...</article>
    <article id="0565" data-scroll-index="1">content...</article>
    <article id="5686" data-scroll-index="2">content...</article>
```

I am trying this with jquery code:

```
var scrollindex = 0;
$('article').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-scroll-index', scrollindex);
    scrollindex++;
});
```

But no accomplishment. Any auggestions?

Comment: Are you sure? It's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/qBf2s/

Comment: The code you have posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2nzpK/ Is there any other code that could be causing a problem? You could try checking your console for errors.

Comment: First off use the custom data attribute (`data-something`), not some made up attribute.

Comment: why not just use the index passed in `.each(function(index)`

Comment: Make sure you have added the references to jquery on your page. Look in your network tab of your browser devtoolbar and see if your Jquery file reference is ok.

Comment: Working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2nzpK/1/

Comment: @j08691 I have actually "data-scroll-index" attribute name. I am not getting any error or warning in console.

Comment: I don't know what you guys are saying but checkout this fiddle, I don't find what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/2nzpK/4/

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The line should be `show($(this).attr("data-scroll-index"));` http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2nzpK/5/

Comment: sorry my bad, I forget to change!

Comment: Ok, but why I am not able to see the change in page source?

Comment: You need to look with the browser's developer tools. Viewing the source only shows what the server delivers to the browser, not the changes made by JS.